# WebBrowser PrintPreviewDialog Size

Tags: c#, dialog, size, browser

I have a WebBrowser

```
private WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
```

and when I click on a Button, it should open a PrintPreviewDialog and show me the WebBrowser.

So when the user clicks on a button, this code is being executed:

```
private void PrintPreviewCommandExecute()
{
    wb.DocumentText = ReportPage;
    wb.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(450000, 750000);
    wb.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(450000, 750000);
    wb.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(450000, 750000);
    wb.DocumentCompleted += wb_PreviewDocumentCompleted;
}

void wb_PreviewDocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    wb.ShowPrintPreviewDialog();
}
```

ReportPage contains a HTML string. As you can see, I'm trying to set the Dialog size somehow (with ridiculous big numbers...), but the window size is not being changed.

So when the Dialog is being shown, it looks like this:

http://i.imagebanana.com/img/s474xiyk/Unbenannt.png

How can I change the size of the PreviewDialog (in the top left corner)?

Comment: You can't, this is baked into IE.  All you can do is ask for the dialog to be displayed.  Something pretty messed up on your machine to get the dialog that small, it will work better on your user's machine.  Double-check by using the dialog in IE, ought to be small as well.  Follow up at superuser.com

Comment: Thanks for the info, but what do you mean with user machine? Ain't I'm working on a "user machine"?... I'll try the same at home on 3 different PC's to test it. - Do you think that when I use another version of the IE that it could be displayed in another format (bigger height/width)?

Comment: @DanVogel No... Worked in a company and had to deal with this problem, but I was just a student there and I'm not working anymore, so I didn't try to search for a solution.